# Replacement for kotlin coroutines

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my projects, I'm using coroutines heavily.

Currently I'm in my process of converting my workflow from kotlin to java(Weird I know..).

What I'm asking is - what is the kotlin coroutines equivalent in java? I read about AsyncTask, but for my understanding it's not used anymore

Comment: There is none, really.  There are various Java async frameworks, such as RxJava, but they work very differently from coroutines.

Comment: Depends on which specific part of coroutines, you can look at Thread pools with Executors, RxJava, plain old callbacks, ... But there isn't a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: I am curious to know who is forcing you to convert from Kotlin to Java?  Use RxJava to replace Coroutines.